# How can I compare model saved data in django from controller?

Tags: python, html, django

I built a django powered webapps,where I used a model field called average CGPA(avg_cgpa) which is a DecimalField in Django model. Also I used a for loop on controller/template to generate all separate data about a student.Now my intention is to compare avg_cgpa data for every row of model to generate a new

tag.Where it will be print different result for each student.
Like, if avg_cgpa > 2.00 it will be print pass,otherwise fail !
I did tried as you have seen on template but its not working,please come up with your helpfull answer.

```py
(Django model here)

class Management(models.Model):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Present_address = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    Permanent_address = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    avg_cgpa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_id
```

```html
(Here is the template)

{% load static %}
{% include 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% include 'banner.html' %}


<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for x in student %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><strong>ID : </strong> {{ x.student_id }}</h5>
                     <hr class="my-4">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static "images/hat.png" %}"><hr class="my-4">
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><strong><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i> </strong> {{ x.first_name }} {{ x.last_name }}</h6>
                    <hr class="my-4">
                    <p class="card-text">Father's Name : <strong>{{ x.father_name }}</strong></p>
                    <p class="card-text">Mother's Name : <strong>{{ x.mother_name }}</strong></p>
                    <p class="card-text">Address : <strong>{{ x.Permanent_address }}</strong></p>
                   <p class="card-text"><strong><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> {{ x.contact }}</strong> </p>
                   <p class="card-text">Avg CGPA : <strong>{{ x.avg_cgpa }}</strong></p>
                   {% if x.avg_cgpa > "2" %}
                        <p class="card-text">Condition : <strong>Pass</strong></p>
                   {% endif %}
                  </div>
              </div>
              </br>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </br>
</div>

{% include 'footer.html' %}
{% endblock%}
```

I did tried if condition within for loop,but no result as outcome.Is it possible to retrieve data by comparing model data in django ?

Comment: did you try this => `{% if x.avg_cgpa > 2 %}` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider adding a property to your model that returns whether it is a pass or not

```
class Management(models.Model):

   @property
   def passed(self):
       return self.avg_cgpa > 2
```

This can then be used in the template `{% if x.passed %}`, it can also be used in other parts of your code and is a bit more readable

Comment: Thank you so much.